# Unable to import QtCore from Pyside

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyside

I have windows 8.1 machine with two Python installations 3.4.4 and 3.2.2
Everything looks okay in python 3.4.4

```
Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:15:05) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import PySide
>>> from PySide import QtCore
>>> QtCore.__version__
'4.8.5'
```

but on using 3.2.2 i get an error

```
Python 3.2.2 (default, Sep  4 2011, 09:51:08) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import PySide
>>> from PySide import QtCore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    from PySide import QtCore
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I have tried reinstalling PySide, and adding  "C:\Qt\4.8.6\bin,  but these steps have not made any difference.

Interestingly the QtCore.**version** reports version 4.8.5 although i have Qt version 4.8.6 installed.

How could i get PySide working on the python 3.2.2 too?

**Edit:**
I also tried reinstalling QT, this time using "qt-opensource-windows-x86-vs2008-4.8.6.exe" from Qt homepage

Comment: Did you use pip to install pyside ? This should work for both Python 3.4 and 3.2: <PATH_TO_PYTHON_SCRIPTS_FOLDER>\pip install -U pyside. BTW, you don't need Qt on you system, because the pyside packages allready contains all Qt libraries, and also the UI designer and translator. Please send here the full log if you got errors when installing pyside via pip command.

Comment: Yes i did use pip and did not get any errors while installing. Thank you for the tip - i really assumed PySide depended on Qt on the system.

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled everything (python and packages) from scratch and now it seems to work. This time i used python version 3.2.5 though. I'm not sure if starting from scratch or updating 3.2 python fixed it.